# How to create a GNU GAS macro that expands to an expression like "(x+y*240)*2"?

Tags: assembly, macros, gnu-assembler

I'm building a program for ARM Linux using GAS, but I want to do some macros to make my development some more smart. Then I want to know:

How could I do a macro for this: `(x+y*240)*2`, were `x` and `y` are `int`, that will be used like this:

```
mov r0, MACRO_SHOULD_BE_CALLED_HERE
```

And how could I do a macro that should be called like this:

```
JUST_MACRO_CALLED_HERE_TO_DO_SOMETHING
```

That will just do something that is already defined inside it, like a print function for example.

Also, if I need some arguments on the macro or a function call. How I could do it?

*PS: `r0` is an ARM register, like `eax` of x86*

Comment: What are `x` and `y`: registers or always constants? For constants, consider using `.altmacro` and `%`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776992/gas-altmacro-macro-with-a-percent-sign-in-a-default-parameter-fails-with-oper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GAS vs NASM comparison - Macros](http://web.archive.org/web/20090215122116/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gas-nasm.html) shows ways of doing parametrized macros, but it's simple substitutions.

Comment: Link is down now, but it's still availabe [at the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20090215122116/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gas-nasm.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an inline gcc sample of the first type.

```
int foo(unsigned short *p)
{
        int c;
        asm(".macro pixw nm, x, y\n"
            " .set \\nm, (\\x+\\y*240)*2\n"
            ".endm\n"
            "pixw pixo,1,2\n"
            "ldrh  %0, [%1, #pixo]\n" : "=r" (c) : "r" (p));
        return c;
}
```

Or in assembler,

```
.macro pixw nm, x, y
 .set \nm, (\x+\y*240)*2
.endm
pixw pix10_2,10,2 ; variable pixo is macro as parameters
 ldrh  r0, [r1, #pix10_2] ; get pixel offset.
```

Often people use a 'C' pre-processor instead.

Comment: `.set` is what I needed. Thanks. Docs explicitly state that it is okay to `.set` the same symbol multiple times in an assembly, in case anyone is uneasy with using it in a macro.

Comment: The intent of this macro/code is to address a 16-bit display with a width of 240.  This is a common embedded memory mapped display.  It is also seems to be what the OP wanted.  You could use it to access similar banks of registers; for instance a multi-SPI,  EHCI, MII, etc.  It is basically a way to handle a two-dimensional array or an array of 'structs', where x is the offset and y would be the count.  The display use is why I originally looked at this question and did not find a sufficiently good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen an assembler that supported macros like you want for your first example.  The second example is pretty straightforward though - even the most basic assembler documentation should cover it.  For GNU `as`, you probably want something like:

```
.macro JUST_MACRO_CALLED_HERE_TO_DO_SOMETHING
    ...
.endm
```

Put whatever instructions you want in place of the `...`.

Be careful with assembler macros that you don't stomp on a bunch of registers that you were using to hold important data.  Usually a function call is a better way to solve these problems.

Comment: But if I need some arguments on the macro or a function call. How I could do it?