# How to declare a define in ARM assembly and use it?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I am trying to work with [icachetest](https://github.com/plattypus/Android-4.0.1_r1.0/tree/master/system/extras/tests/icachetest) and it has a file in it named `icache.s` contains:

```
#define LOOP \
        subs    r2, r2, #1             ; \ 
        mov     r0, r0                 ; \
        mov     r0, r0                 ; \ 
        mov     r0, r0                 ; \
        mov     r0, r0                 ; \
        mov     r0, r0                 ; \
        beq     end_loop               ; \
        mov     r0, r0                 ; \
```

I am using   `arm-eabi-as` to compile this project but I get this error:

```
  AS     icache.S
icache.S: Assembler messages:
icache.S:16: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `\'
icache.S:17: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `\'
icache.S:18: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `\'
icache.S:19: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `\'
icache.S:20: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `\'
icache.S:21: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `\'
icache.S:22: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `\'
icache.S:23: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `\'
icache.S:52: Error: bad instruction `loop LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP'
icache.S:53: Error: bad instruction `loop LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP'
icache.S:54: Error: bad instruction `loop LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP LOOP'
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `as` - just need to use `gcc` so that the preprocessor gets invoked, e.g. `gcc -Wall icache.S ...`.

Comment: as is the assembler, clean assembly will assemble fine with as.  If you are trying some mixed language thing with C code in your assembly then you need the C pre-processors before as is called by gcc.  basically you dont use define in asm you use a macro.

Comment: @PaulR will `gcc -Wall` run the as `as` well?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point - if you use gcc as the driver then it takes care of preprocessing (and various other things) and passes the preprocessed asm source to `as`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LOOP` is a **C** macro as others have pointed out.  As it has no parameters or conditionals, it is easily replaced with a `gas` macro.

```
.macro  LOOP
    subs    r2, r2, #1
    mov     r0, r0
    mov     r0, r0
    mov     r0, r0
    mov     r0, r0
    mov     r0, r0
    beq     end_loop
    mov     r0, r0
.endm
```

It will behave the same as a `#define` after this, with the caveat that only one is allowed per line.  The ARM assembler does allow multiple op-codes on a line (as far as I know).

You can use `.rept` to repeat the macro.

```
.rept 2048
   LOOP
.endr
```

Comment: See similar: [Macros using gas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127905/macros-using-gas) and the [GAS macro docs](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html).

Comment: How do I call the LOOP macro?

Comment: You should just need `LOOP`.  You might need a '\r\n' in the source.  I don't know if you can have multiple macro **calls** on a line.

Comment: Yes you are right but is it possible to write macro run LOOP 2048 times instead of writing 2048 lines?