# Gas altmacro macro with a percent sign in a default parameter fails with "% operator needs absolute expression"

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I want to create a macro like the following:

```
.altmacro

.macro assert_eq a, b=%eax
    LOCAL ok
    #...
.endm
```

To be used as:

```
assert_eq $1
assert_eq $1, %eax
```

I want `.altmacro` for `LOCAL` (I see the other possibility of using `\@`, but I want `LOCAL`).

But when I try to compile this I get:

```
Error: % operator needs absolute expression
```

I am guessing that this problem is created by the fact that `b=%eax` is attempting to use another feature enabled by `.altmacro`: [Expression results as strings](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Altmacro.html#Altmacro),
since without `.altmacro` I could write this without problem.

If this is true, how do I escape that for my macro to work? If not, what is wrong with my code?

Bonus question: how to use `%`?

GAS version: 2.23.52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into a very similar problem where I wanted to pass registers as arguments to a macro that required the use .altmacro. The fix that worked was to enclose the registers in <> and place ! before %. So try changing your macro to be

```
.macro assert_eq a, b=<%eax>
```

and if you ever want to call your macro with a register as an argument do

```
assert_eq <%eax>, <%ecx>
```

Comment: I could not observe any effect with exclamation mark `!` (except not compiling :-)), can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

With `.altmacro`, any parameter passed or default with a percent `%` gets treated as an expression.

Sample usage:

```
.altmacro

.macro PERCENT x
    mov $\x, %eax
.endm
mov $0, %eax
PERCENT %1+1
/* eax == 2 */

.macro PERCENT_DEFAULT x=%1+1
    mov $\x, %eax
.endm
mov $0, %eax
PERCENT_DEFAULT 1
/* eax == 1 */
PERCENT_DEFAULT
/* eax == 2 */
```

To prevent that expansion from happening, we have to do as [mentioned by mfbutner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26685346/895245):

```
.altmacro

.macro PERCENT x
    mov \x, %eax
.endm
PERCENT <%ebx>

.macro PERCENT_DEFAULT x=<%ebx>
    mov \x, %eax
.endm
PERCENT_DEFAULT
```

Since this expansion happens only to arguments, not inside the macro itself, one alternative if we are sure that the argument is a register, is to put the percent inside the macro:

```
.macro PERCENT_ESCAPE_REG x
    mov %x, %eax
.endm
mov $0, %eax
mov $1, %ebx
PERCENT_ESCAPE_REG ebx
/* eax == 1 */
```

But this has the downside that we cannot pass immediates like `$1` anymore:

```
PERCENT_ESCAPE_REG $1
```

This is to me a huge turnoff to using `.altmacro`, as it requires callers to use extra noise on every call...

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
.att_syntax noprefix
```

and than call the macro as

```
assert_eq $1, eax
```